# why is a fatal error being thrown when the statements run fine on their own

Tags: php, prepared-statement

```
<?php 
require_once 'functions.php';
try{
  $stmt=$connection->prepare("
    SELECT ACT_ID, NAME, COST, DESCRIPTION, EXTRA_DETAILS, REFID,IMAGE
    FROM ACTIVITIES
    WHERE ACT_ID = ?
  "); 
  $stmt->bind_param("i",$_GET['id']);
  $stmt->execute();
  $result=$stmt->get_result();
  $actData=getAllData($result);

  if ( isset($_SESSION["user_id"]) && $_SESSION["user_id"] != "" ){

      $stmt=$connection->prepare("
        SELECT id
        FROM google_users 
        WHERE id=? AND gender IS NOT NULL
      ");
      $stmt->bind_param("i",$_SESSION['user_id']);
      $stmt->execute();
      if ($stmt->fetch()){
        $actData[0]["HAS_USER_INFO"]=TRUE;
      }

      //PROBLEM STATEMENT1##############################
      $stmt=$connection->prepare("        
        SELECT `REG_ID` 
        FROM `ACTIVITY_REGISTRATION` 
        WHERE `USER_ID` = ? AND `ACTIVITY` =?
      ");
      $stmt->bind_param("ii",$_SESSION['user_id'],$_GET['id']);
      $stmt->execute();
      if ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $actData[0]["REGISTERED"]=TRUE;
      }  
    }

    //PROBLEM STATEMENT2#########################3
    $stmt=$connection->prepare("        
      SELECT O.`COST`, O.`DESCRIPTION`, O.`OPTION_ID` 
      FROM `ACTIVITIES` A, `ADD_OPTIONS` O 
      WHERE `ACT_REF` = `REFID` AND `ACT_REF` = ?
    ");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$actData[0]["REFID"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result=$stmt->get_result();
    $opData=getAllData($result);
  }catch(Exception $e){
      echo $e->getMessage();
  }

  $stmt->close();
?>
```

I have been getting Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean on "PROBLEM STATEMENT2"

**What I have done already:**

1) checked SQL for errors: I ran it in phpmyadmin as well as in php(on ther own) with and without the `` quotes and got no errors for either of the problem statements. I have also tried reducing them to very simple SELECT * statements without the bind and it still fails.

2) assigned unique variable instead of overriding $stmt: no change in error

3) checked column names, datatypes and Restricted words: they all check out

4) checked values of bounded variables: they all exist

**What I found:**

strangely, if I remove PROBLEM STATEMENT1, PROBLEM STATEMENT2 will run without error, similarly if i remove PROBLEM STATEMENT2 the rest of the code functions normally and if i swap their positions in the code the error always goes to the leading statement.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Based from other threads here, use `$db->errorInfo()` and `$db->errorCode()` to get the reason for your error.

Comment: mysqli(in my case $connection)->errno and error both return 0 and "" respectively at point of failure

Answer (score 0):

Solution was found here: [MySQLi failing to prepare a statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729278/mysqli-failing-to-prepare-a-statement)

Statement quote:

> you probably bumped into the problem that you can't create an other statement while there are still results/result sets pending for the previous statement.
>   see http://docs.php.net/mysqli-stmt.close:

Closing the statement and opening a new one solved the problem. For anyone else that may come across this issue, a good practice might be not to run too many prepared statements one after the other but instead create a function for each statement that handles it's own execution and closing. This should prevent potential result build-ups.